# Make custom types appear in Xcode's documentation popup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation

I want to achieve the similar result for my own code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is XCode's documentation viewer and [Document Sets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/Documentation_Sets/000-Introduction/introduction.html).

Check out this tutorial on working with Doxygen, a popular docgen that works well with XCode: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/DoxygenXcode/_index.html (not for XCode 4)

If you are using XCode 4, check out these articles:

- [Using the Doxygen Helper in Xcode 4](http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/05/14/using-the-doxygen-helper-in-xcode-4/)
- [Easy Doxygen code snippets for Xcode 4](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/easy-doxygen-code-snippets-for-xcode-4/)
- [DOXYGEN SHORTCUTS IN XCODE4](http://www.brokenrul.es/blog/?p=761#.T6OCietYsu8)

Comment: I saw it. But is it normal that classes from standard libraries use it and I need to install it manually?

Comment: @Gargo: If you are using XCode4, I just added a few more links that'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[AppleDoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) achieves the result you're looking for.